# Webpack Dev Server - URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using webpack 3.5.3 and have come across an issue when running webpackDevServer with https:

> Fetch API cannot load webpack-internal:///./src/utils/analytics/gtm.js. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

This issue is caused by a GTM script i'm calling on a user action. Initially I tried running the server using https by setting https to true.

While the site launched and worked fine on https I still had the CORS error.

After reading into it a bit more I saw a lot of SO answers advising to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to all like so in my wepack dev server config:

```
headers: {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
},
```

Even with CORS enabled for all I still get the same error. I cant seem to find where i've gone wrong so if anyone has had a similar issue before and might know why i'm still getting the error that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: update to webpack 4